# What is a regex in django for the following url?

Tags: regex, django, url

What is a regex in django for the following url? It should run the view when it's on this page: `http://localhost:8000/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct regex would be:

```
r'^$'
```

It should match when you hit either localhost:8000 or localhost:8000/

the ^ character means "at the start of the line,", the $ character means "at the end of the line." So basically this regex says something like, "when the absolute path to the resource is blank (i.e. you are at the root of the server) then return this view."

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r'^/$', 'index', name='index')
```

Comment: I had the ^ and $ the wrong way around - writing answers while drunk is a horrible idea. :P

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('views',
    (r'^$', '{{insert your view name here}}'),
)
```

Check out this documentation here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/